# SQL Server to PL/SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql

This is sql server script that needs to be turned into Oracle 11g:

```
select p.locale, q.everecondis, [0] as No, [1] as Yes, 
[0]* 100.0/([0] + [1]) as [pctNo],
[1]* 100.0/([0] + [1]) as [pctYes]
from
(select p.locale, q.everecondis, s.enr1yr
from s, q, p
where s.student_info_key = q.student_info_key 
and s.pse_school_key = p.pse_school_key and s.enr1yr >=1) as tbl
pivot
(count(enr1yr) for enr1yr in ([0],[1])) as pvt
order by locale, everecondis
```

How do I get this to run in PL/SQL on Oracle 11g? (New to PL/SQL)

Comment: What's your (specific) question?

Comment: How do I turn it into PL/SQL to run on Oracle 11g?

Comment: Try running it in Oracle, and fix whatever is broken. Both are based on SQL, so the basics are the same. It's the vendor-specific functions/conventions that will be different. So just fix whatever functions aren't the same.

Comment: The query doesn't really make sense. You have `s.enr1yr >=1` but are pivoting on `enr1yr in (0,1)`

Comment: @chris: Please comment on the answers themselves, rather than editing comments into your question. You can comment on answers on your own questions; the 50 rep requirement is only for others' questions and others' answers on them.

Answer (score 3):

The query doesn't seem to make sense as the `s.enr1yr >= 1` in the `WHERE` clause excludes records that you are later trying to count but a literal rewrite that should work in both SQL Server and Oracle AFAIK is

```
SELECT p.locale,
       q.everecondis,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.enr1yr = 0 THEN 1 END) AS No,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.enr1yr = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Yes,
       AVG(CASE WHEN s.enr1yr = 0 THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS [pctNo],
       AVG(CASE WHEN s.enr1yr = 1 THEN 100.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS [pctYes]
FROM   s
       JOIN q
         ON s.student_info_key = q.student_info_key
       JOIN p
         ON s.pse_school_key = p.pse_school_key
WHERE  s.enr1yr IN (0,1)
GROUP BY p.locale,
         q.everecondis      
ORDER BY p.locale,
         q.everecondis
```

I changed the `WHERE` clause to `s.enr1yr IN (0,1)` as that seems by far the most probable desired semantics. Let me know if this is not the case!

Comment: I think it's just the `<` being incorrectly typed as `>`, i.e. `<= 1`

Comment: You need an `ELSE 0.0` for AVG

Comment: @Richard - Yep just noticed that when I clicked through to see your earlier comment. thanks!